# JSR 303 Bean Validation Custom Constraint in Spring Boot Rest endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

I've got a Spring boot application serving some REST endpoints. I'm trying to create some reusable logic around filters, paging, sorting etc.

For the PagingInfoDto object, I'm wrapping limit and offset request params.

I'm doing some bean validation to ensure limit and offset meet some cusomt rules.

This all works fine when I implement it like so:

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/somevalue", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ResponseEntity<Object> list (
        @Valid PagingInfoDto pagingInfoDto){
```

PagingInfoDto:

```
@Paging(limitDefault = 2)
public class PagingInfoDto
{
   private boolean hasMore;

   private Integer offset;

   private Integer limit;

   public Integer getOffset() {
    return offset;
   }

   public void setOffset(Integer offset) {
    this.offset = offset;
   }

   public Integer getLimit() {
    return limit;
   }

   public void setLimit(Integer limit) {
    this.limit = limit;
   }

    public boolean isHasMore()
    {
        return hasMore;
    }

    public void setHasMore(boolean hasMore)
    {
        this.hasMore = hasMore;
    }

}
```

PagingRequestFiltervalidator:

```
public class PagingRequestFilterValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Paging, PagingRequestFilterDto> {

    private static final String MISSING_OFFSET = "offset cannot appear without limit";
    private static final String ZERO_LIMIT = "limit cannot be 0";
    private static final String MISSING_LIMIT = "limit cannot appear without offset";


    private int limit = 0;
    @Override
    public void initialize(Paging paging) {
        this.limit = paging.limitDefault();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(PagingRequestFilterDto pagingRequestFilterDto, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        boolean validity = true;
        constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        /**
         * Offset has to be greater than or equal to Zero
         */
        if(pagingRequestFilterDto.getOffset() == null) {
            pagingRequestFilterDto.setOffset(0);
        }

        /**
         * Set undefined or invalid limit to default to value from the annotation
         */
        if(pagingRequestFilterDto.getLimit() == null
            || pagingRequestFilterDto.getLimit() > limit) {

            pagingRequestFilterDto.setLimit(limit);
        }
```

Paging Annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {PagingRequestFilterValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Paging {
    String message() default "Invalid Paging Details";

    int limitDefault() default 20;

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is annotate the parameter PagingInfoDto parameter with the @Paging Custom Constraint so that each endpoint can set it's own limitDefault.

Like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/somevalue", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<Object> list (

            **@Paging(limitDefault = 2)** PagingInfoDto pagingInfoDto){ ...


 @RequestMapping(value = "/someothervalue", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<Object> otherlist (

            **@Paging(limitDefault = 5)** PagingInfoDto pagingInfoDto){...
```

The above doesn't fire validation of the object. I feel like it's as simple as I'm missing something very obvious...

I found a blog post which seems to indicate that you need to implement a custom Bean validator:

http://blog.trifork.com/2009/08/04/bean-validation-integrating-jsr-303-with-spring/

My implementation

```
@Component
public class BeanValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator, InitializingBean {

    private Validator validator;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = validatorFactory.usingContext().getValidator();
    }

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(target);
        for (ConstraintViolation<Object> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
            String propertyPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
            String message = constraintViolation.getMessage();
            errors.rejectValue(propertyPath, "", message);
        }
    }
}
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Spring Data's `Pageable` does the same thing exactly  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html

Comment: The fact that I'm talking about paging is arbitrary. The question is regarding Bean Validation.